# Is there a way to directly deploy an iOS app permanently to a device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment, software-distribution

Is it possible to deploy an app for personal use to a single iPhone?

In an ideal scenario I could just install the app from XCode to my device, where it lives permanently alongside my other apps.
I don’t need any services besides local notifications, CoreData and preferably on-device file storage.
It would be nice to be able to update the app later, but that would have to be without losing local data.

I know there are on-device testing provisions but as I understand it, the app expires after some time (at most a year).

Deployment through the App Store or other layers beyond XCode is not a problem as long as the app doesn’t become publicly available.

Comment: Do promo codes fit your needs? After approval you can generate up to 100 codes, I think they're intended to be distributed as marketing tool, but we often issue them to employees for some last minute testing before release. This [link](https://medium.com/uvimate/how-to-generate-and-redeem-ios-app-promo-codes-in-2018-for-the-new-app-store-835d6a1654c1) describes the process a bit. I think to issue an update you'd need to issue a full release or a new promo code.

Comment: These promo codes look good, I’ll have to investigate further. Also, your excellent question made me realise I should describe what I want in terms of what I do need, instead of what I don’t need. I’m editing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the Business program. You can deploy as usual but share the application only to specific companies that have enrolled to the business program.
[Apple Custom apps](https://developer.apple.com/business/custom-apps/)
Test flight build expire after 90 days.
Ad-hoc build after 1 year.
Custom apps never.

Comment: Do you sborride?